# Excel not sorting numbers correctly on pivot table

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table, excel-pivot

It's as the title says, my excel pivot table is not sorting numbers corretly.

When I create the pivot table from my dataset, the goal is to have the data sorted by year, week number, and the Keys sorted by the PM_Value (decreasing order) as shown here. The "PM_Value" column is a Calculated Field.

| Year | WeekNum | Key | Value 1 | PM_Value | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-SFS-R757-L05 VAC1 | 5.777 | 833 | 6.936 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS7-R125-L05 | 4.407 | 833 | 5.292 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS7-R008-L05 VAC | 5.347 | 833 | 6.421 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-SFS-R735-L05 VAC1 | 5.757 | 830 | 6.938 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS4-R007-L06 | 13.431 | 829 | 16.195 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-SFS-R804-L05 VAC1 | 5.646 | 829 | 6.811 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS7-R083-L06 | 4.983 | 749 | 6.656 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS7-R107-L06 | 4.941 | 749 | 6.600 |

The problem is that the PM_Value column has zeroes (or possibly errors shown as zeroes), and these values are not sorting correctly. Currently de sorted pivot table is like de one below.

| Year | WeekNum | Key | Value 1 | PM_Value | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-SFS-R757-L05 VAC1 | 5.777 | 833 | 6.936 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-SFS-R735-L05 VAC1 | 5.757 | 830 | 6.938 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS7-R038-L06 | 5.055 | 749 | 6.753 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS7-R081-L06 | 5.081 | 748 | 6.795 |
| 2023 | 1 | .... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS7-PRJ52-L12 | 4.641 | 33 | 139.684 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS7-PRJ53-L12 | 4.190 | 29 | 144.750 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-SFS-R715-L06 RGD | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-SFS-R719-L06 RGD | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-SFS-R789-L06 RGD | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS4-R054-L05 VAC | 14.131 | 811 | 17.416 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS4-R015-L06 | 15.052 | 802 | 18.776 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS4-R031-L05 R2 | 4.856 | 789 | 6.156 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2022-GS4-R058-L06 | 12.639 | 731 | 17.290 |

I already tried to deactivate de "custom lists" sorting check box on the pivot table options, changing the order of the sort (i.e. Year/Month/Key, Key/Year/Month, etc) but nothing makes the zeroes stay on the bottom of the sorted column.

Has anyone experienced anything like that and could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the calculation of "PM_Value" is a division, and some of the zeroes were DIV/0 errors showing as zeroes and these errors that were messing with the sort. I used a IFERROR(calc,0) on the Calculated Field and the problem disappeared!